# Change the Mouse click detection of Pygame to a serial Input

Tags: python, pygame, chess

is it possible to change the mouse-click detection of Pygame to an external input for example?
Im trying to build a chess code, which is receiving Positions from an Arduino. So in the following Code im trying to convert my input string (b2) to the Position (2,2) and give it back in my main as the x,y information for pygame.

```
def objectdetection(screen, game_state, valid_moves, square_selected):
    ser = serial.Serial('/dev/ttyUSB0', 9600, timeout=1)
    ser.flush()
    while True:
        if ser.in_waiting > 0:
            Position = [ser.readline().decode('utf-8').rstrip()]

    if Position == "b2":
        return (2, 2)



main:
            elif e.type == objectdetection:
                if not game_over and human_turn:
                    location = objectdetection()  # (x, y) location of the mouse
                    col = location[0] // SQUARE_SIZE
                    row = location[1] // SQUARE_SIZE
                    if square_selected == (row, col) or col >= 8:  # user clicked the same square twice
                        square_selected = ()  # deselect
                        player_select = []  # clear clicks                                                   
                    else:
                        square_selected = (row, col)
                        player_select.append(square_selected)  # append for both 1st and 2nd click           
                    if len(player_select) == 2:  # after 2nd click                                           
                        move = ChessEngine.Move(player_select[0], player_select[1],game_state.board)        
                        for i in range(len(valid_moves)):
                            if move == valid_moves[i]:
                                game_state.makeMove(valid_moves[i])
                                move_made = True
                                animate = True
                                square_selected = ()  # reset user clicks
                                player_select = []                                                          
                        if not move_made:
                            player_select = [square_selected]
```

sadly it doesn't work so easy. Is it overall possible to change the Mouse detection from pygame to an external input?
Thanks for any help.

Comment: @rabbid76 im sorry im new to python, so i really have barely knowledge. Also im German, i just tried to quickly convert it into english. i thought i will have to create a function which reads the input (b2) and converts it to the location (2,2) and i called it objectdetection. I called the location position, because location is already used by Pygame. After what i learned, with return (2,2) the function objectdetection should give out (2,2) at the end. So i thought if i set location = objectdetection   (which should be 2,2) could work like this

Comment: Yes thats true, but i have to code this for a project, and my professor doesnt care, that its really hard for people who begin with python.

Comment: normally my code is:             
elif e.type == p.MOUSEBUTTONDOWN:

                if not game_over and human_turn:

                    location = p.mouse.get_pos()  # (x, y) location of the mouse . 
i wonder why i cannot just change the p.mouse.get_pos to the direct (x,y) location.  Since i dont want to make a move directly, i want that when i pick up a pawn, the fields where he can go will highlight and the field where the pawn is on will send a message to my python with b2.

Comment: What does your question have to do with chess?

Answer (score 0):

Write function for the object selection and put the code in the function:

```py
def select(row, col)
    global square_selected, player_select, move, move_made, animate

    if square_selected == (row, col) or col >= 8:  # user clicked the same square twice
        square_selected = ()  # deselect
        player_select = []  # clear clicks                                                   
    else:
        square_selected = (row, col)
        player_select.append(square_selected)  # append for both 1st and 2nd click           
    if len(player_select) == 2:  # after 2nd click                                           
        move = ChessEngine.Move(player_select[0], player_select[1],game_state.board)        
        for i in range(len(valid_moves)):
            if move == valid_moves[i]:
                game_state.makeMove(valid_moves[i])
                move_made = True
                animate = True
                square_selected = ()  # reset user clicks
                player_select = []                                                          
        if not move_made:
            player_select = [square_selected]
```

You can call the function when the mouse is clicked:

```py
for e in p.event.get():
    if e.type == p.QUIT:
        # [...]

    elif e.type == p.MOUSEBUTTONDOWN:
        if not game_over and human_turn:
            col = e.pos[0] // SQUARE_SIZE
            row = e.pos[1] // SQUARE_SIZE
            select(row, col)
```

And you can call the function when you receive a position:

```py
position = objectdetection(.....)
if position != None:
    row = position[0]
    col = position[1]
    select(row, col)
```